# Permitir ao usuário executar o programa passo a passo

Tags: java

Olá, estou na parte de desenvolvimento de meu TCC que consiste de uma ferramenta de apoio ao ensino de grafos (mais precisamente de alguns algoritmos, como Caixeiro Viajante, Arvore Geradora Mínima, etc...) e gostaria de permitir que o usuário executasse o programa no modo passo a passo, de forma que o usuário possa controlar a execução dos algoritmos e ter tempo de observar as alterações.

Gostaria de sugestões de como implementar o recurso de execução passo a passo, se existe algum padrão, biblioteca ou se alguém já implementou algo semelhante e poderia compartilhar o código para estudo.

Comment: Você quer fazer um tipo de depuração? como o netbeans e o eclipse faz?

Comment: Exatamente @Edi. Gomes, claro sem tantos recursos... mas disponível ao usuário...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem duas respostas para o que você quer.

1. A resposta simples consistem preparar o ambiente para que você mostre como executar o algoritmo passo a passo mas não implementar um debugger de código totalmente funcional. Mais ou menos como o apresentado aqui [nesta pagina](http://algorithms.openmymind.net/sort/bubblesort.html)
2. A resposta complicada é você entrar no [site da documentação do debugger da JVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/architecture.html#jdi)
   e tentar compreender como o debugger funciona. Ou ainda [ver como foram feitas algumas implementação simples do debbuger](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com.br/2009/03/java-using-jpda-to-write-debugger.html) mas acredito que não seja exatamente o que você esteja procurando.

Recomendo que você utilize a primeira solução. Prepare anteriormente cada uma das telas para cada tipo de algoritmo que você quer executar com botões para
iniciar e ir para próximo passo.
Para executar passo a passo um algoritmo você precisa desconstruir seu loop e transformar ele em funções, por exemplo:

Bubble sort:

```
public static void bubbleSort(int[] array) {
    for (int j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - j; i++) {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                int tmp = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = array[i];
                array[i] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Você precisa primeiramente extrair a parte interna assim:

```
public static void bubbleSort(int i , int[] array) {
    if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
        int tmp = array[i + 1];
        array[i + 1] = array[i];
        array[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Agora você precisa colocar os inputs corretos para esta parte simulando a execução. Segue exemplo completo para te dar uma ideia:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Sorter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int[] array = {5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3};
        final List<Integer> contextValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length - j; i++) {
                contextValues.add(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Array:");
        printArray(array);
        System.out.println();
        //executa a cada 1 segundo um passo do bubble sort
        final Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            int step = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("--------------");
                System.out.println("Passo " + step);
                bubbleInPosition(array, contextValues.get(step));
                printArray(array);

                if (step > contextValues.size()) {
                    t.cancel();
                }
                step++;
            }
        }, 0, 1000);

    }

    public static void printArray(int array[]) {
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int i : array) {
            System.out.print(" " + i + " ,");
        }
        System.out.print("]");
    }

    private static void bubbleInPosition(int[] array, int i) {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
            int tmp = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = array[i];
            array[i] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

No lugar do Timer você teria a chamada do botão de próximo passo.
Esta seria uma ideia simples, mas pode ser aplicada a vários algoritmos.

Comment: Eu estava pesquisando a possibilidade de usar o JPDA ou uma [Arvore Sintática abstrata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). Sua primeira ideia surge como mais uma opção  e a segunda traz um exemplo que vai ajudar a decidir se uso ou não o JPDA. Obrigado :)

Comment: Olá @Johny. Se aprovou a resposta de um check na resposta para ajudar outros que podem ter esta mesma duvida.

Comment: Usei JPDA para a implementar um debugger permitindo a execução passo a passo.